# create formula for download Attachment and File

Tags: lightning, attachment, files

I have a id of Attachmant  OR File is stored in a variable now want to write formula to download attachment or File is it possible ?

Comment: Formula fields don't have variables. Are you working in Apex, Process Builder, Flow? Are you trying to generate a hyperlink to download a file? You need to add a lot more detail and specificity to your question.

Comment: Its Simple formula I am trying no Process builder  Simply trying to populate  a single hyperlink field for download File and Attachment as its URL is diffrent

Answer (score 3):

You can create a formula field kind of HYPERLINK which will either download the Attachment or open the file in the browser

```
HYPERLINK("servlet/servlet.FileDownload?file=" + recordId , Name + "<valid extension>","_blank")
```

For file, formula will be like this, Here it is downloading an image file.

```
HYPERLINK("sfc/servlet.shepherd/version/download/" + recordId + "?asPdf=false&operationContext=CHATTER", 
Name + "<valid extension>",
"_blank")
```

Comment: It will not  work for File as url is diffrent

Comment: Then provide an example at your question. Don't post a broad question

Comment: well it is defined in the problem statement , I have Single ID which could be contentID populated when upload file or Attachment ,  Now want to create a formula based on contentID to dowload File and Attachments.  What formula you have given will work only for Attachment not for File

Comment: You need to state these things *in your question*. Please make edits there instead of continuing comment threads, and take a moment to read through [How to Ask](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: check my updated answer

Comment: Can you please tell in which cases these URLs will be generated?